# Activity indicator as one table view loads another

Tags: iphone, activity-indicator

I've been trying for about a day to get a table cell to display an activity indicator while it loads a new view.  Upon didSelectRowAtIndexPath I'd like to display the indicator while the following runs

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:subKeywordController animated:YES];
```

This controller then runs a fairly intensive SQL query

I've searched the web and read dozens of posts but none seem to help with my specific problem.  I understand that I need to run the indicator in another thread because the push and subsequent load takes precedence but I'm unsure how to do it.  I thought about running the SQL query in the controller before but that's getting very messy.

The odd thing is that I've been using [MBProgressHUD](http://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) to display busy cursors in this same table view with no issues.  It's only when I apply a search and then select one of the results that causes this error:

**bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x1d79b0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...**

The app continues on the iPhone but crashes the simulator.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your task in the controller is holding up the UI code (but you probably already know that!). A cheap and easy way of solving this is to put a tiny delay on starting your slow task (in this case your SQL query) using a timer :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // instead of running the SQL here, run it in a little bit
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(doSQL:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    // Show the please wait stuff
    [activityIndicator setHidden:NO];
}

- (void)doSQL:(NSTimer *)timer {
    // Do your sql here
}
```

The other way of solving this is to move your SQL into a seperate thread :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // instead of running the SQL here, run it in a little bit
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSQL) withObject:nil];

    // Show the please wait stuff
    [activityIndicator setHidden:NO];
}

- (void)doSQL {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // Do your sql here

    // Tell the main thread
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doneSQL) userInfo:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    // Cleanup
    [pool release];
}

- (void)doneSQL {
    // Update your UI here
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks.  I was coming on here to delete this as it was a silly mistake on my part in not calling 'resignFirstResponder'

But thanks for the answer though.